# clang try catch not working on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, haskell

```
$clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

magick_wrapper.cpp

```
#include <Magick++.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "magick_wrapper.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick; 

void hello_world() {
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}

void initialize_imagick() {
    static int isInitialized = 0;

    if(!isInitialized) {
        InitializeMagick(NULL);
        isInitialized = 1;
    }
}

void throw_exception_test() {
    try {
        throw runtime_error("just a test");
    } catch (exception &error) {
        cout << "error occured: " << error.what() << endl;
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "an exception has rasie" << ", but we don't know what it is" << endl;
    }
}
```

haskell code with ffi

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import           Foreign.C
import           Foreign.Ptr


foreign import ccall "hello_world"
    c_hello_world :: IO ()

foreign import ccall "throw_exception_test"
    c_throw_exception_test :: IO ()

main = do
    c_hello_world
    c_throw_exception_test
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "magick_wrapper.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "main start" << endl;
    throw_exception_test();
    cout << "main ends" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

make file

```
CC=clang

all: test testc

testc: magick_wrapper.o main.o
    $(CC) -o testc main.o magick_wrapper.o `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs` -lc++

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -c main.cpp

test: test.hs magick_wrapper.o
    ghc -v -o test test.hs magick_wrapper.o `Magick++-config --ldflags --libs` -lc++

magick_wrapper.o: magick_wrapper.cpp
    $(CC) -c `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags` magick_wrapper.cpp -stdlib=libc++

clean:
    rm *o *hi test testc
```

std output from test (haskell ffi)

```
$ ./test
hello world
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: just a test
Abort trap: 6
```

std ouptut from testc (pure c)

```
$ ./testc
main start
error occured: just a test
main ends
```

ghc verbose output

```
*** C Compiler:
clang -m64 -fno-stack-protector -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -c /var/folders/kp/f2t2ps216tl3p4t6jsplr9400000gn/T/ghc26839_0/ghc26839_4.c -o /var/folders/kp/f2t2ps216tl3p4t6jsplr9400000gn/T/ghc26839_0/ghc26839_5.o -I/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.8.3/lib/ghc-7.8.3/include
*** Linker:
clang -m64 -fno-stack-protector -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -m64 -o test -Wl,-no_compact_unwind test.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-7/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-7/lib magick_wrapper.o '-lMagick++-6.Q16' -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16 '-lMagick++-6.Q16' -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16 '-lc++' -L/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.8.3/lib/ghc-7.8.3/base-4.7.0.1 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.8.3/lib/ghc-7.8.3/integer-gmp-0.5.1.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.8.3/lib/ghc-7.8.3/ghc-prim-0.3.1.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.8.3/lib/ghc-7.8.3/rts-1.0 /var/folders/kp/f2t2ps216tl3p4t6jsplr9400000gn/T/ghc26839_0/ghc26839_5.o -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_static_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_static_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_static_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_static_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_static_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Wzh_static_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziInt_I8zh_static_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziInt_I16zh_static_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziInt_I32zh_static_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziInt_I64zh_static_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziWord_W8zh_static_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziWord_W16zh_static_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziWord_W32zh_static_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziWord_W64zh_static_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_static_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_con_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_con_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_con_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziPtr_FunPtr_con_info -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_con_info -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_False_closure -Wl,-u,_ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_True_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziPack_unpackCString_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_stackOverflow_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_heapOverflow_closure -Wl,-u,_base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nonTermination_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnMVar_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnSTM_closure -Wl,-u,_base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nestedAtomically_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziWeak_runFinalizzerBatch_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziTopHandler_flushStdHandles_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziTopHandler_runIO_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziTopHandler_runNonIO_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziConcziIO_ensureIOManagerIsRunning_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziConcziIO_ioManagerCapabilitiesChanged_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziConcziSync_runSparks_closure -Wl,-u,_base_GHCziConcziSignal_runHandlers_closure -Wl,-search_paths_first -lHSbase-4.7.0.1 -lHSinteger-gmp-0.5.1.0 -lHSghc-prim-0.3.1.0 -lHSrts -lCffi -liconv -lgmp -lm -ldl
link: done
```

it seems during unwind, catch code was ignored by some reason. this behavior seems can only repeated under OSX with clang. I have tried gcc under Linux which works perfectly fine.

Comment: I jus built this, same OS and clang as you, stripping out the setup to Magick since I don't have it, and the output when invoking your test function was : `error occured: just a test`, which is to be expected. Does Magick they installing their own exception handler? (and note: I built with `-stdc++11` not that it should matter). Also, try namespace qualifying the `catch (std::exception const& error)` not that it should matter either.

Comment: Magick::Exception inherited from std::exception. Catching std::exception should also catch Magick::Exception. I tried with gcc 4.8 on OSX (homebrew version), it works with ONLY throw and catch std::exception but not with Magick since Magick was compiled with clang. (I got a error message says Object code not recoginzed, it seems gcc 4.8 homebrew version is broken)